# Many requestes in azure between web sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi what is the correct way to get two different web sites to talk to each other within Azure.

Today we tried to just make them talk through their Rest Api's but after 1000 requests we got locked out from the web site our calling web site were calling.

We know we can use a service bus to make them talk. But we would really like to be able to use the rest api:s.

Are there limitations in how much a web site can call another web site within azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several limits on websites, depending on what type you are using (free, shared, basic, standard)

With Free and Shared, you are limited on the CPU usage (60 minutes/day and 240 minutes/day) but also just for 2.5 minutes per 5 minutes. So when doing a lot of requests without a pause, you will run into this.

Another restriction on free websites is the data limit of 165 MB.

With Basic and Standard you have your own machine, so these restrictions don't apply

http://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#websiteslimits